# Как запретить удаление на FireBase?

Tags: javascript, api, безопасность, firebase

Как сделать так что бы все кто хотел могли читать и добавлять данные  базу на Firebase но удалять их мог только я?

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно настроить `FIREBASE RULES` где вы укажите что только админ может удалять записи

в таком случае все могут толкай читать дание

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false      
}
```

}

в этой страхе талкаю вас на мысль как это должно быть премьерно

```
 ".write": "auth != null && auth.isAdmin == true"
```

покопайтесь здесь [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/) должны найти ответ